# spring - 404 error with the url http://www.springsource.org/tags/form

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, maven, spring-mvc

Currently, I use a Maven project. I don't have any Tomcat server. I use the local google app engine server to test my application.

I would like to use the spring tags, especially the 'form' tags.

I copied the spring-form.tld file from the spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF. It's done.

But when I launch the app engine server and I go to this url : http://www.springsource.org/tags/form , I've a 404 error.

Do you have any solutions ?

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't need to copy spring-form.tld in WEB-INF. Just make sure the spring-webmvc jar is on your classpath (WEB-INF/lib).

Comment: My spring-webmvc jar is well in WEB-INF/lib but it doesn't work

Comment: The 404 error is because you can not visit the  http://www.springsource.org/tags/form like any other jsp page as it is simply the taglib uri for the spring-form.tld, resides in the spring-webmvc jar. Could you please post actual problem